# Action of a Subgroup of Symmetric Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

Let H be a Subgroup of $S_n$ having the action on {1,2,...n} transitive. Moreover if H is generated by Transpositions, I need to show that H is the whole group.

What I am thinking is that If H is not $S_n$ then there is atleast one transposition which is not in H. Somehow using this I need to contradict the Transitivity.

Any suggestions, or Hints will be appreciated.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If all the generating transpositions fix an element $x$, then $H$ fixes $x$ and can't be transitive.

Comment: But how can I  say that such an element exist ? @Berci

Comment: The assumption that $H$ is transitive rules out the existence of such an $x$. Therefore, all elements are involved among the generating transpositions.

Comment: Ohk. I want to prove it by contradiction if there is some transposition which is missing in H then how could I get one. Isn't it that existence of such an x is assured by the missing transposition? @Berci

Comment: Well, if each element is moved by one of the given transpositions, then (you can prove by induction) all transpositions are in their generatum.

Comment: Ohkz... I think I get it now but induction on what ? @Berci